# Increase column by percentage every X rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                amount
01-01-2020      100
01-02-2020      100
01-03-2020      100
01-04-2020      100
01-05-2020      100
01-06-2020      100
01-07-2020      100
01-08-2020      100
01-09-2020      100
01-10-2020      100
01-11-2020      100
01-12-2020      100
```

I need to add a new column which starts with 100 and increases the value by 10% every 4 months, ie:

```
                amount      result
01-01-2020      100         100
01-02-2020      100         100
01-03-2020      100         100
01-04-2020      100         100
01-05-2020      100         110
01-06-2020      100         110
01-07-2020      100         110
01-08-2020      100         110
01-09-2020      100         121
01-10-2020      100         121
01-11-2020      100         121
01-12-2020      100         121
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
pct = .1
df['result'] = df['amount'] * (1 + pct) ** (np.arange(len(df))//4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for each 4 months with [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) for groups, then get 10% by multiple Series by 100 with divide 10 and last add `100`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)

df['result'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4MS')).ngroup().mul(100).div(10).add(100)
print (df)
            amount  result
2020-01-01     100   100.0
2020-02-01     100   100.0
2020-03-01     100   100.0
2020-04-01     100   100.0
2020-05-01     100   110.0
2020-06-01     100   110.0
2020-07-01     100   110.0
2020-08-01     100   110.0
2020-09-01     100   120.0
2020-10-01     100   120.0
2020-11-01     100   120.0
2020-12-01     100   120.0
```

If datetimes are consecutive and always each 4 rows is possible use:

```
df['result'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 4 * 100 / 10 + 100
print (df)
            amount  result
2020-01-01     100   100.0
2020-02-01     100   100.0
2020-03-01     100   100.0
2020-04-01     100   100.0
2020-05-01     100   110.0
2020-06-01     100   110.0
2020-07-01     100   110.0
2020-08-01     100   110.0
2020-09-01     100   120.0
2020-10-01     100   120.0
2020-11-01     100   120.0
2020-12-01     100   120.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to substract boolean vlaues for each period:

```
df['result'] = df['amount'] * (1 + pct) ** (np.arange(len(df))//4) -  np.arange(len(df))//4
```

this is how you will have correct results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32143228)